# Deploying a WCF service to the shared host environment

Tags: .net, wcf

I created a very simple WCF class library and added this project to the solution that has a web project. I added a reference to the service from the web project. Locally, everything works as expected.

When I do a copy site to my hosting provider, I get all sorts of errors. Currently I have this error:

```
Parser Error Message: The binding at system.serviceModel/bindings/wsHttpBinding does not have a configured binding named 'WSHttpBinding_IService1'. This is an invalid value for bindingConfiguration.

Line 146:    </bindings>
Line 147:  <client>
Line 148:   <endpoint address="http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/"
Line 149:    binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService1"
Line 150:    contract="ServiceReference1.IService1" name="WSHttpBinding_IService1">
```

What's the correct way of deploying a WCF service to a shared host?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely config - as your error really says:

> Parser Error Message: The binding at
>   system.serviceModel/bindings/wsHttpBinding
>   does not have a configured binding
>   named 'WSHttpBinding_IService1'. This
>   is an invalid value for
>   bindingConfiguration.

It is looking for a binding configuration with the name of 'WSHttpBinding_IService1' and is not finding it.

Check your config file (web.config for IIS-hosted, app.config for self-hosted) - does it contain all the settings it needs? Most likely not.....

Comment: I don't know where to start looking. I am completely a noob in WCF. Which sections of the web.config files should I post for people to give an idea what might be wrong?

Comment: The WCF configuration is everything in the `<system.serviceModel>` section